# Перевод описания знака «Общительный»

Tags: дефект, локализация, знаки

В оригинале описание знака «[Talkative](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/884/talkative)» звучит так:

> Post 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in chat.

У нас [переведено так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/65/talkative):

> Опубликовал в чате 10 сообщений, получивших хотя бы по одной звезде.

Из перевода следует что каждое из 10 сообщений должно получить по звезде, в то время как на самом деле для получения знака достаточно одной звезды на любом сообщении.

Предлагаю вариант:

> Опубликовал 10 сообщений в чате, из которых хотя бы одно получило звезду.

Comment: Не согласен. Из оригинала это никак не следует. На мой взгляд переведено всё правильно.

Comment: @XelaNimed судя по получившим такой знак, там действительно достаточно одной звезды при общем кол-ве в 10 сообщений. [Пример участника](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11220374/stephane-aulery?tab=recent)

Comment: Утвердил [предложенный перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/5993).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а не может это быть ошибкой движка? Имею ввиду, не является ли это некой "подгонкой" перевода под существующие реалии?

Comment: @XelaNimed очень [маловероятно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71751/339911).

Comment: @XelaNimed вопрос я задал после того как получил этот знак. У меня только одно сообщение в чате со звездами.

Comment: @XelaNimed добавил [вопрос об изменении формулировки](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328326/339911), чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Большое спасибо! Если опубликуете как ответ, то я смогу быстрее закрыть тему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предложенный перевод

> Опубликовал 10 сообщений в чате, из которых хотя бы одно получило звезду.

Был [утвержден](https://ru.traducir.win/string/5993) и появился на сайте, за что спасибо [@αλεχολυτ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84)